# Actionbutton not working for first time in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have used this code for a simple app to receive system and site name from users. And I have problem for the second time press the "submit" button. For example, if user has pressed "submit" directly without select system/select site, it will pop up "Please make sure system is not empty ." This is the first time press "submit" but when user has selected system and the site then pressed "submit" the second time, it does not work. Does any one know how to solve it?

Here is my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyTime)
library('tools')

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("test"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput('system', '* Select System:', width = '100%',
                     choices = c("a","b","c"), multiple = FALSE,
                     options = list(
                       placeholder = 'Please Select Site',
                       onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                     )),
      

      selectizeInput('site', '* Select Site:', width = '100%',
                     choices = c("A","B","C"), multiple = FALSE,
                     options = list(
                       placeholder = 'Please Select Site',
                       onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                     )),
      hr(),
      actionBttn(inputId = "submit", label= "Submit for Processing")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4("Test review")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # observe submit
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    print("test input submit button 2")
    if (input$system=="") {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Error",
        "Please  make sure system is not empty."
      ))
    }else if (input$site==""){
      print("test1")
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Error",
        "Please make sure site is not empty."
      ))
    }else {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Good",
        "success"
      ))
      }
    }, once = TRUE)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Remove `once=TRUE`. From [`?observeEvent`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.5.0/observeEvent.html), that argument is for *"Whether this observeEvent should be immediately destroyed after the first time that the code in handlerExpr is run. This pattern is useful when you want to subscribe to a event that should only happen once"*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code explicitly asks for the observed behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Didn't realise it is this line causing the issue